# Запросы не выполняются последовательно AJAX. Почему?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Подскажите, в чем моя ошибка?

Я хотел бы отправлять `AJAX` запросы последовательно, но у меня почему то они уходят все равно все вместе.

https://jsfiddle.net/t01jsowv/1/

Comment: как по вашему, что обозначает первая А в AJAX ?

Comment: @teran , Asynchronous JavaScript and XML . Я понимаю, что запросы асинхронны, так же можно установить false , что заморозит браузер. А мне хотелось бы, чтобы новый запрос начинался после того как вернет ответ прошлый запрос.

Comment: @ИванЕмельяненко смотри пример с async/await в дубликате

Comment: @grundy не считаю это дубликатом.

Comment: @ИванЕмельяненко, почему? :-)

Comment: @grundy , ну вы примените решение озвученное там, под мою задачу )

Comment: @ИванЕмельяненко, ну так отлично применяется же :-) у тебя есть цикл, в цикле вызываешь функцию с `await` - все работает как надо :-)